# convert unix time stamp to NotesDateTime in SSJS

Tags: xpages-ssjs

How can I create with SSJS (e.g. under a computed field) a date object from a unix time stamp?

The date stamp is a string collected from a Notes view.

Comment: A JavaScript date object or a NotesDateTime object?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use this to convert the unix timestamp to a java date ?

```
java.util.Date time=new java.util.Date((long)timeStamp*1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat to parse a string containing a timestamp with a certain pattern and then return a java.util.Date object.

Tommy Valand has created [an easy to use library for that converting between date and string](http://dontpanic82.blogspot.dk/2010/04/xpages-code-snippet-for-datestring.html).